# question on the weak formulation of a pde

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am trying to find a function u such that it solves equation 1 and 2 here:

[image]

Can someone explain to me how 1 and 2 implies the last equation?  (the vector n here is the normal that goes "out" of the Omega domain)
I understand the concept of weak formulation but I don't see where the part with the normal went. Can someone tell me if this formula is accurate? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take equation (1) and multiply by $v\in H^1(\Omega)$, and integrate over the volume $\Omega$ to give:

$$\int_\Omega-v(\Delta u)\ dV-\kappa^2\int_\Omega uv\ dV=\int_\Omega fv\ dV$$

The first term can be rearranged, using [Green's first identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_identities) to

$$-\int_\Omega v(\Delta u) \ dV = \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v\ dV-\int_{d\Omega} v (\nabla u.n)\ dS$$

and the latter integral can be rearranged using equation (2) (to substitute for the $\nabla u.n$ term) to

$$-\int_{d\Omega} v (\nabla u.n)\ dS=\int_{d\Omega} uv\ dS -\int_{d\Omega} gv\ dS.$$

Putting it all together gives the equation you marked with an arrow:

$$\int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla v\ dV-\kappa^2\int_\Omega uv\ dV+\int_{d\Omega} uv\ dS=
\int_\Omega fv\ dV+\int_{d\Omega} gv\ dS$$

[incidentally I wrote the volume integrals in terms of dV to emphasise it's a volume element]